# Flickering lights, how to determine who to call

Tags: electrical

I've read numerous "flickering lights posts" and the answers range from bad bulbs to bad wiring to a bad neutral.  Here's what I've determined:

- They (the tenants) report it only happens when either the 3D printer or the clothes washer is running, but not the electric stove.
- It's all the lights throughout the house, and not just the LEDs.
- Moving the printer to a different circuit didn't fix anything.
- Even an incandescent bulb on a circuit less than 10' from the breaker panel flickers.
- The voltage at the panel when *not* flickering (measured just after the master breaker, hot to neutral): One leg 116.7v.  The other leg 124.4
- The voltage at the panel when *they are* flickering (hot to neutral): One leg 118.8v.  The other leg 126.4
- The voltage at the outlet of a flickering bulb: 118.8v.
- Previously we had a problem with the lights brightening when a load kicks in.  We had an electrician out who found some iffy neutrals and other unrelated issues.  He reseated the neutrals and the problem went away.  But that's about when the flickering started.
- The house was built in 1964 and is located in the U.S.

So my question is: Who do I call next, the power company or an electrician?

Comment: Is it an active flicker or more of a dimming situation? Does it happen the entire time the printer or washer is running or just at start-up?

Comment: Does it happen during windy or rain/snow situations? It could indicate a failing weatherhead.

Comment: It's not affected by the weather.

Comment: I see, any my other questions?

Comment: That is an awfully high difference between the two legs. Each leg is within the "normal" range, but that really seems a bit off - I normally see < 1V difference.

Comment: The lights only flicker when the printer's bed heater is on (either warm-up or during operation) but not the heaters on the extruder nozzles.  The washer only causes flickering when the mechanism is doing something (so fill and drain don't cause any problems.)

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I agree, 5% difference seems pretty high for something coming off a transformer.

Comment: Those are just 120v appliances, right?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Yes, 120V, and we're 60Hz in this part of the country.

Comment: Which part of which country?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Illinois

Comment: Interesting, which part of the US doesn't use 60Hz?

Comment: A bit odd that the bed heater causes problem, but not the motors that move the nozzle.  It might come down to getting the power company and a electrician.  For a house with a single transformer, both legs should be equal, if no power is used or balanced.  The printer and washer might need checking since they seem to cause the flickering, and nothing else, so far.

Comment: Have you moved the printer to a circuit *on the other leg*?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact That's a good idea.  She has moved the printer to a different outlet, but I can't say it was on a different leg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I think you had a lost neutral all along

Each house/dwelling has a local Grounding Electrode System aka "ground rods" and the wires running out to them.  Each *main* panel has a *Neutral-Ground Equipotental Bond* (N-G bond) whose job is to keep neutral near earth potential. This works with the ground rods to [keep this from happening](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRHyqouJPzE) (UK homes don't have ground rods).

So thanks to the N-G Bond, there's a party happening in your main panel where house neutrals, utility neutral, house grounds and ground rods all come together.  Got it?

[image]

So what happens in a Lost Neutral?  [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJvyb_WujZg), ***except*** the neutral connection actually has an alternate path (a bit byzantine but it does work).   Your neutral -> your N-G bond -> ground rods -> *the dirt* -> neighbor's ground rods -> neighbor's N-G bond -> neighbor's neutral.

This path has some resistance, being dirt and all, but still, it will somewhat limit how far neutral will wander away from the center. **This reduces the symptoms of a Lost Neutral**.

What changed is your electrician "Tuned Up" your Grounding Electrode System to get it performing better.  (it was probably broken; given the liability that creates I would have your guy make the rounds to all your properties and check it there).

**Thus, all the electrician did is *reduce the severity* of the symptoms** and that seemed like a victory - but the underlying Lost Neutral condition remains.

The power company should fix that for free in most cases.

Comment: Upvoted - have to agree, maybe the neutral isn't totally lost but it at least has problems. That's a big difference between the two legs.